# How to set different global variable values for release and debug mode C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, release

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC web application using C#. I have a set a global variables, for example:

```
public static class Global
{
    public const string RootUrl = "http://url/";
}
```

I want to set them with different values for release and debug mode. Could anyone give a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: You should not hard-code URLs in an application.  Use web.config and have different configurations for debug and release mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [preprocessors directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) for different debug/release values.

```
#if DEBUG
   public const string RootUrl = "http://url/";
#else
   public const string RootUrl = "http://another/";
#endif
```

Comment: And what if I have a configuration named Test and I want to do it for that very config.

Answer (score 6):

Although this is not direct answer, your question seems to be more configuration-related and I recomend to use `web.config` configuration for distinct environments. Look at your solution:

[image: web.config.debug and web.config.release]

Moreover, storing settings in external file is much better than embeding them into application's binaries. What if one of the URL's changes? You will have to recompile and deploy new version of application.

The simplest way is to use `appSettings` section in the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="GlobalValue1" value="1" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the following:

```
#if !DEBUG
    // Your code here
#endif
```